significance of "preferred" embodiments?
I've read some utility applications that explicitly claim certain embodiments are preferred, while some applications explicitly mention that none of the embodiments should be viewed as preferred.
what is the significations of designating certain embodiments as preferred?

There a few issues. One is that if there is an issue in interpretation of a claim it might be argued that if it is read as not covering the preferred embodiment then the interpretation may be flawed.
It has fallen out of favor to designate a preferred embodiment due to judges imputing limitations from the embodiment into claims that don’t actually require those limitations.
In the U.S. there is a requirement to disclose the “best mode” of implementing the invention g th hat is known by the inventing team. That has been watered down by the AIA law from 12 years ago but it still is a requirement. Some misunderstand that the best method must be identified as such. Hence a preferred embodiment.  But identifying the best  minded is not required, just including it is enough.
